# Stack 2D array to 4D

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list with 6 2D arrays with the same dimension `(200, 200)`. Every three consecutive arrays can be stacked up to a 3D array.

Desired output:

```
array = (200, 200, 3, 2)
```

I am familiar with np.dstack:

```
n = 6
array = []
for i in range(n):
    x = np.random.randn(n1, n2)
    array.append(x)
array = np.dstack(array)
```

Speed should be considered as I am working with large data sets.

---

Edit:
I created images for testing:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/afb0a2fbfbd8b6047a68dad41b56a0d520200509184625/761355

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Adapted Paddy's answer:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import glob
from natsort import natsorted

DIR = (Set folder path with the test images)

list_path = glob.glob(DIR + "/*.png")
list_path_sorted = natsorted(list_path)
array = []
for i in range(len(list_path_sorted)):
    image = np.array( io.imread(list_path_sorted[i]) )
    array.append(image)
a = np.dstack(array).reshape(200, 200, 3, 2)

a.shape
>>> (200, 200, 3, 2)
```

Issue: The order in the third dimension doesn't match. To test this:

```
plt.imshow(a[:,:,0,0]) -> should show picture with A1
plt.imshow(a[:,:,2,0]) -> should show picture with A3
plt.imshow(a[:,:,0,1]) -> should show picture with B1
plt.imshow(a[:,:,2,1]) -> should show picture with B3
```

Comment: And question is?

Comment: I stuck with the condition that three consecutive arrays in a list forms a 3D stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dstack` as you suggested then `reshape` the resulting array:

```
import numpy as np

# six arrays of (200, 200)
n = 6
array = []
for i in range(n):
    x = np.random.randn(n1, n2)
    array.append(x)

# EDIT to use 'F' ordering
a = np.dstack(array).reshape(200, 200, 3, 2, order='F')

a.shape
>>> (200, 200, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It seems the order of the arrays are not correct. I replaced the line: x = np.random.randn(n1, n2) with random test images to test this.

Comment: Made an edit to fix the problem. Normally uses 'C' (row) ordering, but it can also use 'F' (column, F for Fortran) ordering. In this case the images should be in the correct place, ie. `a[:,:,0,0] = 'A1'`, `a[:,:,0,1] = 'B1'` (whereas before `a[:,:,0,1] = 'A2'`).

Answer (score 1):

I can't play with your images, so I'll generate a list of distinctive (2,2) arrays:

```
In [412]: alist = [np.arange(i,i+4).reshape(2,2) for i in range(6)]                                    
In [413]: alist                                                                                        
Out[413]: 
[array([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]]), array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]), array([[2, 3],
        [4, 5]]), array([[3, 4],
        [5, 6]]), array([[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]), array([[5, 6],
        [7, 8]])]
```

With `dstack` we get a (2,2,6) array

```
In [414]: arr = np.dstack(alist)                                                                       
In [415]: arr                                                                                          
Out[415]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],

       [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]])
```

The (3,2) reshape produces:

```
In [417]: arr.reshape(2,2,3,2)                                                                         
Out[417]: 
array([[[[0, 1],
         [2, 3],
         [4, 5]],

        [[1, 2],
         [3, 4],
         [5, 6]]],


       [[[2, 3],
         [4, 5],
         [6, 7]],

        [[3, 4],
         [5, 6],
         [7, 8]]]])
```

Sounds like you aren't happy with that layout (your edits are bit unclear).  We can transpose values

```
In [419]: arr.reshape(2,2,2,3).transpose(0,1,3,2)                                                      
Out[419]: 
array([[[[0, 3],
         [1, 4],
         [2, 5]],

        [[1, 4],
         [2, 5],
         [3, 6]]],


       [[[2, 5],
         [3, 6],
         [4, 7]],

        [[3, 6],
         [4, 7],
         [5, 8]]]])
```

With this last arrangement,

```
In [431]: _419[:,:,2,0]                                                                                
Out[431]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
In [432]: _413[2]       # alist                                                                               
Out[432]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

In [435]: _419[:,:,0,1]                                                                                
Out[435]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
In [436]: _413[3]                                                                                      
Out[436]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: I apologise for the poor edits. Please see the updated edits with a working code and download link to the images. Just set the DIR to the download folder with the images. I hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: Assuming your images are in the list in the order `[A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3]`, then my last ordering is one you want - see my edit